# How to get configurable attributes of a configurable product using the Magento API?

Tags: api, magento

how can I get the configurable attributes of a configurable product using the Magento API? I'd like to get a list of all individual products that are part of a configurable product and the attributes used to configure them.

For example, a configurable product called SHIRT might be configured by COLOR and SIZE. I'd like to get all individual products: SHIRT S BLUE, SHIRT S RED, SHIRT L BLUE, SHIRT L RED. Is it possible to do using the API only?

Something like this but using the API?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24764511/47883